# Nested route in react-router v6 is not working

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am using `react-router-dom` v6.

```
const App = () => (
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<Login />} />
    <Route path="login" element={<Login />} />
    <Route path="/" element={<BaseLayout />}>
      <Route path="system" element={<SystemList />} />
      <Route path="system/create" element={<SystemCreate />} />
    </Route>
  </Routes>
);
```

Since `/system` and `/system/create` do not have shared components (they are completely different screens, but the url structure from the `/system` screen to the `/create` screen), the `Outlet` is not used.

On the other hand, both `<SystemList>` and `<SystemCreate>` screens are nested screens of `<BaseLayout>`, they are expressed in `Outlet` of `<BaseLayout>`.

#### Problem

`localhost:3000/`, `localhost:3000/login`, `localhost:3000/system` all working. But `localhost:3000/system/create` is not working(No screen appears
).

I tried changing the order of `/system` and `/system/create`, and I changed the location to the same level as `/` and `login`, but it still doesn't work.
What's the problem?

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue as you describe. Check here in this running [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nested-route-in-react-router-v6-is-not-working-p0p9up) of your code here. It's odd that you have ***two*** routes rendering on `path="/"`, but it all still seems to work. Are you seeing any errors in the console?

Comment: @DrewReese Thx. I checked the codesandbox and it is the same as my code. And when I check the console, a 404 Not Found error occurs. I don't understand why it doesn't work (in my code) when a path more than 2depth is entered.

Comment: Maybe try updating react-router to latest? Could be a bug on your version.

Comment: @DrewReese Yes. I' using latest version...

Comment: `react-router-dom@6.3.0` is the latest as of right now. That is the version you are on? Feel free to fork my sandbox, double check all the installed package versions, and add more of your code to see if you can create a running demo that reproduces the issue that we could inspect and debug live. There's got to be a minor/subtle difference *somewhere*. In the meantime I have a minor route refactor that I'd suggest you apply, if you'd like I could provide that in an answer.

Comment: @DrewReese Yes. I'm using react-router 6.3.0 version :) The difference from your code is guessed by the webpack config setting. Even though the historyApiFallback setting is set to true, it is strange to send a request to the server in case of deeper depth.